# Casperjs doesn't work on debian and ubuntu os, getting the innerHTML of a knockoutjs data-bind tag. It works on windows

Tags: linux, windows, knockout.js, casperjs

I am writing a casperjs script. It extracts the text of a span tag, which content is created by knockoutjs data-bind. My code works perfectly on windows, but it doesn´t work on linux (either on debian or on ubuntu). If I write the this.getHTML() in a txt file, all data-bind elements are not loaded in DOM.  They only appear as an array in a script tag.
The version of my phantomjs is 2.1.1. I have tried with Casperjs 1.1.0-beta3 and the master branch, with no success. Can someone help me? I need to use debian os.

HTML Tag

```
<span class="product-name" data-bind="visible: nameLabelVisible(), 
text: selectedNameLabel(), css: { disabled: isDisabled }">Dog</span>
```

Casperjs Script

```
var url='http://exampleurl.com';
var selector='span.product-name';
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled:false,
        loadImages:  true,       
        loadPlugins: true,  
        javascriptEnabled: true
    },
});
casper.start(url);
casper.wait(5000);
casper.then(function(){
    var texto = this.evaluate(function(selector){
        var s = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
        return s;
     }, selector);
    this.echo("result: " + texto);  
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Result:

```
result: null
```